# Send an email without any API in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

- I want to send an email by using SMTP Protocol with integration and not using any dependencies and
  any API.
- Give me proper solution with step by step process.
- Not reflecting into exiting code and run it has without any errors.

Comment: Hi! We are generally suggested (by SO/SE) to be nice to newbies to platform, but people don't tend to follow suggestions freely. Your question lacks context and research, Stack Overflow isn't your personal browser. Take a look at [How to ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider editing and expanding on your question. If you are using google translate, consider that [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) speaks more than words. Cheers! <3

Answer (score 0):

- You can't use the SMTP protocol from JavaScript inside a browser. You will need to find a WASM module for this job (if any exists at all).
- If you already have an integration (or you're looking for an integration) - it will most probably has an API and even might be offering an SDK (e.g. MailChimp, SendGrid, Amazon SES, etc.)
- If you want a step by step process of the proper solution - you will have to either make some efforts to search Google and find HowTo's or you will need to pay someone (e.g. through Upwork) to write the steps of the proper solution for you.
- I am not sure what `run it has without any errors` means - but it will certainly not reflect (or perhaps `affect` ?) any existing code because this all will be only new code.